# How to configure font color for LiveContent Coupon Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a coupon definition in the email application which is defined to be a PlainText type coupon image.  When the coupon is generated, the font is black.  I don't see any options for changing this.  How can I change the font color to white?

Comment: Probably isn't any configuration for the color. Have you tried using some sort of inline style combo to alter it?

Comment: The coupon definition's output is an image rendering with the black text standard.  I think a custom AMPScript solution would be needed in order to deviate from the coupon definition's image output. Thank you for your supporting question.

Comment: Ah, right - yeah - I don't think there are other options here.